Vue JS - Live running time elapsed from a date
Currently I have a time elapsed displayed on my blade file. However to see the updated time, I need to refresh everytime. I would like to display a dynamic time lapsed. Is there a way to do it?
My current code is just that I pass a created_date (defined from controller) to the script. From there, I will get the hours, minutes and seconds. (Might do days later). They I return it back to my blade file.
This is a part from my blade file:
<table class="table table-bordered small">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th width="2%">No</th>
          <th width="5%">
              Created At
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(index,row) in records.data" :class="{'NPI_row_color':NPI_Order(row)}">
          <td>@{{index+1}}</td>
          <td>
              @{{ setTimer(row.created_at) }} 
          </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

And this is the vue js script:
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#shopify_marketplace',
          data: {
            //some of data here
          },
          methods: {
            //some other methods here
            onReload: function(){
              //few codes here and there
            },
            setTimer: function(created_at){

                const startDate = new Date(created_at);
                const now = new Date();
                const elapsedSeconds = Math.floor((now - startDate) / 1000);
                
                const day = Math.floor((elapsedSeconds / 3600));
                const hours = Math.floor(elapsedSeconds / 3600);
                const minutes = Math.floor((elapsedSeconds % 3600) / 60);
                const seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60;

                return `${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`;
                
            },
          },
          filters: {
              autoCaps: function(value){
                  if(value != null) {
                      return value.toLocaleUpperCase();    
                  }
              },
          },
          ready: function () {
              this.onReload();
          },
      });
  });
</script>

Image below is what my current display is. But yeah need to refresh everytime to see it update. May I know how can I make the time running and 'ticking?'. I tried to use this setInterval function from javascript but I failed miserably.
current_display

You just have to use the Javascript setInterval function to get a callback once a second.

I tried to use this setInterval function from javascript doesn't look like you did - perhaps you failed only slightly rather than miserably

@JaromandaX let me try again and show you once im done. Im still new to vue js so im not very familiar with it

@muhaz - setInterval is native javascript, so lack of vue familiarity is irrelevant :p

@JaromandaX yes I am aware. it is just i am not sure how I can put it into vue component. im sorry for my lack of experience.

You should change the key to force re-render which will trigger the function, something like this :
<table class="table table-bordered small">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th width="2%">No</th>
          <th width="5%">
              Created At
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(index,row) in records.data" :class="{'NPI_row_color':NPI_Order(row)}">
          <td>@{{index+1}}</td>
          <td :key="currentTime">
              @{{ setTimer(row.created_at) }} 
          </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#shopify_marketplace',
          data: {
              // some of data here
              currentTime: 0 // Add this property to track the current time
          },
          methods: {
              // some other methods here
              onReload: function(){
                  // few codes here and there
              },
              setTimer: function(created_at){
                  const startDate = new Date(created_at);
                  const now = new Date(this.currentTime); // Use the reactive currentTime
                  const elapsedSeconds = Math.floor((now - startDate) / 1000);
                  
                  const hours = Math.floor(elapsedSeconds / 3600);
                  const minutes = Math.floor((elapsedSeconds % 3600) / 60);
                  const seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60;

                  return `${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`;
              },
              startTimer() {
                  // Update the currentTime every second
                  setInterval(() => {
                      this.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                  }, 1000);
              }
          },
          mounted() {
              this.onReload();
              this.startTimer();
          },
      });
  });
</script>

You can read more about the key attribute here.

NOTE : the index is always the second option it should be (row,index), i didn't want to change it since you didn't mention it as a problem but i think it's wrong
